# Predict the target audience for a new brand using data from other brands and customers buying behavior

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, feature-selection, random-forest, recommender-system

Assume a company has a large database about wine, including brand, the taste of the wine, year, place of production, etc, and data of customers' purchase behavior. Now if there is a new brand coming to the company and asking who should the brand sell the product to, how should I approach this question? What kind of data/features should I use from the database? Thank you very much!!